# Country, city, state, Post code table design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have a database in which there is Country, city , states , postcodes in one table with huge set of records. I want to normalize the database structure to avoid redundancy and remove any data duplication. Should I split database and make separate tables for Country, City, state and postcode?

Or merge country , city , state, postcode in Address table?

Comment: How many duplicates of each field are there? You could normalise this down to the street level but without some indication of your data it's impossible to advise. Also it's important to understand the application - finding everyone who lives in a certain postcode has different requirements to simply storing users' addresses

Comment: e.g. In one country there are 1 Million Users and in one city three are 50 thousand user , Similar Case with State, Postcode.

Comment: I follow this advise it's really hard to design a database without knowing the data in it. You should compare the space and speed you will earn, with the complexicity you will add. How many times will you access these values, will you use them all everytime or only the city for once, only the state .... One table per columns means 1 join per column per address and 1 index search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following tables could be used for addresses in North America. Counties (which would also contain Parishes and other similar geographical subdivisions) is US-centric.

In the `addresses` table I allow the `city_id` and `county_id` to be `NULL` because, based on [HLGEM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034/hlgem)'s comment, you can be in a city OR a county but not both in the state of Virginia. The application code would need to enforce the rule that at least one of these fields is not `NULL`.

```
addresses
    id              unsigned int(P)
    street          varchar(50)
    extended        varchar(50) // Default NULL
    city_id         unsigned int(F cities.id) Default NULL
    county_id       unsigned int(F counties.id) Default NULL
    zip             varchar(6) // Will handle all north American zips
    zip4            char(4) // Default NULL
    lat             decimal(10,8) // Allows for ~1mm accuracy at equator. Default NULL
    lon             decimal(11,8) // Allows for ~1mm accuracy at equator. Default NULL

cities
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    state_id            unsigned int(F states.id)
    name                varchar(45)
    fips                unsigned int // Default NULL
    census_code         unsigned int // Default NULL
    census_class_code   char(2) // Default NULL
    gsa_code            unsigned int // Default NULL
    opm_code            unsigned int // Default NULL
```

`city_id` and `county_id` form the Primary key and are foreign keys to their respective tables.

```
cities_counties
    city_id             unsigned int(F cities.id) ---\_(P)
    county_id           unsigned int(F counties.id)--/

counties
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    state_id            unsigned int(F states.id)
    name                varchar(50)
    fips                unsigned int // Default NULL
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

```
countries
    id                  char(2)(P)
    iso3                char(3)(U)
    iso_num             char(3)(U)
    name                varchar(44)(U)
```

See [FIPS state codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_state_codes), [FIPS region codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_region_codes) and [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2).

```
states
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    country_id          char(2)(F countries.id)
    code                varchar(3)(I)
    name                varchar(45)
    fips                unsigned int // Default NULL
```

Comment: Just for future readers who might be thinking about using this model. Even in the US not all cities have counties and not all counties have cities, so be wary of the cities_counties table and always left join to it.  In Virginia, by law you are in either a city or a county, you cannot be in both. This is a legacy from the civil rights era where they used the law to keep the schools segregated.

Comment: @HLGEM - Thank you for the addendum! It's very rare that I have ever used county information myself but I include it in posts like this because someone might need it.